# Связывание данных в angularjs с SQLite

Tags: sqlite, angularjs, binding, ionic

Разрабатывается приложение на ionic (angular.js), с возможностью работы без интернета с данными из кэша. Для кэша я выбрал SQLite.
Если бы приложение было только он-лайн - вопрос со связыванием данных решался бы на уровне ангуляра. Но т.к. между сессиями нужно где-то хранить данные, то возникает вопрос с их синхронизацией. 
Может есть какое-то стандартное решение для организации кэша? А то вручную достаточно муторно.

Comment: можно сохранять  данные в localStorage, для ангуляра есть модули для использования localStorage в ангуляре (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Comment: Знаю, что часто спрашивают про замену LS на SQLite в http://ionicframework.com. Вроде, работает. Но это фреймвок. Переходить на него ради одной фичи, стоит ли?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, Вы считаете что двусторонее связывание данных это "одна фича"?

Comment: @DenniLa2, не заметил тег.